# Regex - Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I need to replace $2 by $1 on notepad++ using regex

**Here is the code :** 
`<context>
    <name>AccountActivation</name>
    <message>
        <source>Azerty</source>
        <translation type="unfinished">Kebab</translation>
    </message>
    <message>`

I want the word "Kebab" to be replaced by "Azerty" (not for only this word)
So i made : 
`(?<=<source>)(\X*?)(?=</source>)|(?<=unfinished">)(\X*?)(?=</translation>)`

But i can't seem to find something for the replace part.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<source>(.+?)</source>[\s\S]+?unfinished">\K[^<]+`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/5AqX6S/1)

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Wow. Perfect... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ATK: You're welcome, glad it helps, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)